# StartActivityforResult brackets meaning

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I'm a beginner in Android and I'd like to know, what is the meaning of the words in brackets in `StartActivityforResult(Intent, "bla bla")`. What does the second term in brackets represent?

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: [Did you think that there might be some info in documentation?](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `Intent serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
    return true;`                     But the value of REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE=1 so how can it pass through another activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public void **startActivityForResult** (Intent intent, int requestCode) Added in API level 1

Same as calling startActivityForResult(Intent, int, Bundle) with no options.

Parameters

- intent   The intent to start.
- requestCode  If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity
  exits.

Quoted from [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). It's like a reply for the calling method.

Comment: Please mark this as answered then Abhi :)